# Reset data for a pattern card

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, personalization

I have an issue where a content author incorrectly tagged a lot of content with a specific pattern card.  Now we need to reset anyone's profile who has that pattern card assigned.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: pattern cards are scored and can't be cleared. But they age out via decay. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/what-does-a-profiles-decay-rate-actually-do

Comment: Ok, that's a good way of looking at it that I hadn't thought of before. It's not ideal of course because it will be slow and still mess up analytics a little bit.  Additionally, everyone who was tagged before today is not usable data, but everyone after today should be usable data, and decay rate wouldn't take that into account.

Comment: In SC9, you should be able to do it via Marketing Automation.  There's a rule 'where the contact matched the specific pattern card in the specific profile'.  You could use that rule to target the pattern card and then use the 'change behavior profile' action to reduce the points.  I'm not marking this as an answer, as I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if it would work on past pattern matches or only future ones?  Because to be honest, I only need it to work on past ones, and I don't think this would work.

Comment: The question requirement was 'we need to reset anyone's profile who has that pattern card assigned'.  My suggestion wouldn't work if you need to select by date as well.